# sharepoint.stackexchange data analysis

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if it's the right place to ask, because it's not a questions actually, it's more like a share.

I've created some data analysis on sharepoint.stackexchange using SE API. This information might be interesting for users who are active here, so I decided that by sharing here more people will see this data analysis.

Here is a link - [SharePoint development state in 2016: story based on sharepoint.stackexchange analysis with Power BI](http://spblog.net/post/2017/01/15/SharePoint-development-state-in-2016-story-based-on-sharepointstackexchange-analysis)

Please share your thoughts in comments and feel free to delete if this question is not appropriate.

Comment: Super interesting analysis! And a lot of findings one could dig deeper into. Great work!

Comment: When looking at number of users who've never used the upvote button do you filter out those with less than 15 reputation? (since we're only awarded Vote Up privilege at 15 rep)

Comment: Nope, just all users without upvotes.

Comment: First of all, excellent analysis, Sergei! On the subject of question-answer ratio, I feel another aspect that I have noticed is that members like to probe (and eventually solve) the question in the comments and that way, the question gets answered without actual answers being posted. Any thoughts on improving this so that the post is marked answered? Maybe a separate topic to discuss? Edit: Discussed here previously http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/343/questions-answered-in-comments

Answer (score 5):

Interesting stats! Moderators have analytics tool as well and we monitor what happens on the site a few times a year. Unfortunately, we can't share the details here, but we can tell that the trend is still strong.

Every year the number of visits, page views, questions and answers have increased. At the same time, the number of posters have remained almost flat averaging on 100 a day.

Interestingly from site graduation (2011/09) to half year 2013 we had an answer-question ratio ranging between 1,5-2. Meaning that every question had on average of 1,5 to 2 answer. From the second half of 2013 and to this date, the number of answers follow the number of answers, meaning that every question gets at least 1 answer on average. But since several questions have more answers than one, a lot of questions remain unanswered. Thankfully, the trend isn't increasing - but it remains a hassle to us that we have 30% unanswered questions. Now some of these unanswered questions have answers, but they are not accepted.

From this we can learn that focus should sometimes switch from only monitor new questions, to unanswered questions of your favorite tags. If all of us active users (100 posters a day) take a fraction of our focus to the unanswered question, we could get better stats and make our site more valuable to others.

On the upside one can interpret the still increasing page views from year to year as 1) We are becoming more and more important in our field and 2) SharePoint and Office 365 is still very much a product of great interest from companies and enthusiasts.